# create two columns based on value in data.frame in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table that is big ~8 million rows. This table has 15 columns with numeric values but those values only can be `0` and another numeric value `specific for that column`. I want to create for each one of these columns two new columns based on the `specific value`. These new values are always specific of columns.

Here is a dummy example how my data looks:

```
mydf1 <- data.frame(ID=1:5, c1n=c(0,1,0,0,1), c2n=c(2,0,2,0,0), c3n=c(0,0,0,3,3))
```

and here is my desired output

```
 > mydf2
   ID c1n c1n_ctr c1n_cas c2n c2n_ctr c2n_cas c3n c3n_ctr c3n_cas
#1  1   0       0       0   2      25      55   0       0       0
#2  2   1      10     100   0       0       0   0       0       0
#3  3   0       0       0   2      25      55   0       0       0
#4  4   0       0       0   0       0       0   3     580    1002
#5  5   1      10     100   0       0       0   3     580    1002
```

The correspondence is always the same, i.e, value of 1 in `c1n` is `(10,100)`, value of 2 in `c2n` is `(25,55)`, value of `3` in `c3n` is `(580, 1002)`.

I know that I can use something like this

```
 mydf3 <- mutate(mydf1, c1n_ctr = ifelse(c1n == 1, 10, 0)) %>%
        mutate(c1n_cas = ifelse(c1n ==1, 100, 0)) %>%
            mutate(c2n_ctr = ifelse(c2n ==2, 25, 0)) %>%
            mutate(c2n_cas = ifelse(c2n ==2, 55, 0)) %>%
            mutate(c3n_ctr = ifelse(c3n ==3, 580, 0)) %>%
            mutate(c3n_cas = ifelse(c3n ==3, 1002, 0))
```

But my real data has 15 columns and it would be a lot of copy paste, is there any clean way of doing it?

Comment: You can always create a function to do the work, and then use lapply to perform the function over all the columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have to write down what the specific values are in some way, then you could use this approach.

```
library(dplyr)
mydf1 <- data.frame(ID=1:5, c1n=c(0,1,0,0,1), c2n=c(2,0,2,0,0), c3n=c(0,0,0,3,3))

c1 <- data.frame(c1n=1, c1n_ctr=10, c1n_cas=100)
c2 <- data.frame(c2n=2, c2n_ctr=25, c2n_cas=55)
c3 <- data.frame(c3n=3, c3n_ctr=580, c3n_cas=1002)

mydf3 <- 
    mydf1 %>% 
    left_join(c1) %>% 
    left_join(c2) %>% 
    left_join(c3) %>% 
    mutate_if(is.numeric, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```